# Opacity returning negative value on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code, that tries to fade the opacity of div `.overlay` when the user is 100vh from the screen bottom. It doesn't work however when the screen changes width as elements grow taller, the opacity function generates a minus number.

The if statement logic is fine, it is the opacity function. Any ideas?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Start to adjust footer opacity at 100vh  
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.overlay').css({
      opacity: function() {
        var elementHeight = $(this).height();
        return 1 + (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.overlay').css({
      opacity: function() {
        return 1;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  background: blue;
}

main {
  background: white;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.add-height{
  min-height: 1200px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="add-height">Hello</div>
</main>
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you please add html code?

Comment: JSFiddle added ^

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/uq6b5oms/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    var opacity = ($(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop()) / $(window).height() - 1; 
    $('.overlay').css({
      opacity: function() {
        return opacity;
      }
    });
  }
});
```